# $Spin(7)$ as stabilizer of a $4$-form

Tags: lie-groups, exceptional-groups, octonions

According to Bryant's work on special holonomy groups, $G_2\subset SO(7)$ may be defined as the group preserving the following 3-form:

$\phi_0=\mathrm{d}x_{123}+\mathrm{d}x_{145}+\mathrm{d}x_{167}+\mathrm{d}x_{246}-\mathrm{d}x_{257}-\mathrm{d}x_{347}-\mathrm{d}x_{356}$

where $\mathrm{d}x_{ijk}=\mathrm{d}x_i\wedge\mathrm{d}x_j\wedge\mathrm{d}x_k$. In a similar fashion, $Spin(7)\subset SO(8)$ may be defined as the group preserving the following 4-form:

$\Omega_0=\mathrm{d}x_{1234}+\mathrm{d}x_{1256}+\mathrm{d}x_{1278}+\mathrm{d}x_{1357}-\mathrm{d}x_{1368}-\mathrm{d}x_{1458}-\mathrm{d}x_{1467}-\mathrm{d}x_{2358}-\mathrm{d}x_{2367}-\mathrm{d}x_{2457}+\mathrm{d}x_{2468}+\mathrm{d}x_{3456}+\mathrm{d}x_{3478}+\mathrm{d}x_{5678}$

**But of course, with this definition, it is not obvious at all that $Spin(7)$ is really a double cover of $SO(7)$. Is there any way to understand this fact?** (that is, which is the point of defining $\Omega_0$ like this?) In the book [On Quaternions and Octonions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568811349) there is a definition of $Spin(7)\subset SO(8)$ related to 'octonions automorphisms' (they are not really automorphisms) which reveals some of this double-cover nature. Perhaps these could be a bridge linking these two sides, but at this moment it is not clear for me. Any suggestion will be welcomed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are at least two sources for this:  First, Harvey and Lawson, *Calibrated geometries* (Acta Math. 1982) proves this (i.e., that the stabilizer of $\Omega_0$ is isomorphic to the nontrivial double cover of $\mathrm{SO}(7)$) using properties of the octonions.  Second you can find a proof that doesn't rely on knowledge of the octonions but instead relies on the classification of Lie algebras and groups in Bryant's *Metrics with exceptional holonomy* (Ann. of Math, 1987, Theorem 4 of Section 2).

There are even more 'direct' (i.e., elementary) proofs available, of course.  If those don't satisfy you, then ask again and I'll sketch one here when I have time.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will read these two sources; I am sure they will be most helpful for me.