# $Spin(7)$ as stabilizer of a $4$-form revisited

Tags: lie-groups, spin-geometry, clifford-algebras, exceptional-groups, octonions

For a better understanding of this question, please see the question and answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188455/spin7-as-stabilizer-of-a-4-form).

In $Spin(8)$ there are plenty of copies of $Spin(7)$; consider, for instance, the antiimage of $SO(7)<SO(8)$ by the double cover for any $SO(7)<SO(8)$ obtained by fixing some direction in $\mathbb{R}^8$. So it is true, there are plenty of $Spin(7)<Spin(8)$ (let's call this subgroups *primitives*).

By the triality automorphism of $Spin(8)$, the $Spin(7)$ subgroups go to other $Spin(7)$ subgroups. But the hot point is that it is not a permutation between primtives subgroups: that is, if we perform triality on a $Spin(7)<Spin(8)$ obtained by fixing $e_1\in\mathbb{R}^8$, then we get a copy $Spin(7)<Spin(8)$ whose proyection onto $SO(8)$ is not a double cover of some subgroup $SO(7)<SO(8)$, but an isomorphism over some $Spin(7)<SO(8)$. And it happens that this $Spin(7)<SO(8)$ may be described as the stabilizer of a 4-form, as described in the link above.

So the corner question is: **Why this $Spin(7)$ obtained by performing triality to a primitive $Spin(7)$ should in fact be so strangely described, as the stabilizer of some 4-form? Is there a nice way to understand this fact?**

Any idea or suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you want to look at the relevant passages in *Spin Geometry* by Lawson and Michelsohn, particularly Chapter IV, Sections 9 and 10, where they explain in general how the square of a spinor can be written as a sum of differential forms.  This gives a general way to see how having a parallel spinor (in any dimension) defines a set of parallel forms and conversely.  This may be the 'nice way to understand this fact' that you seek.

Comment: "and conversely": in general, must every invariant form be the square of some invariant spinor (say, wrt some invariant bilinear/sesquilinear form on complex spinors)?

Comment: @PaulReynolds:  Sorry, I wrote the above in some haste and it's perhaps not as clear as it could be.  I didn't mean to suggest that a parallel form implies a parallel spinor in all dimensions.  That's certainly not true in general.  What I meant was that, *sometimes*, the group of linear transformations fixing some set of forms on a vector space can be characterized as the subgroup that fixes the square of a spinor.  The reference I mentioned above explains this fully.

Comment: Right, thanks, of course, e.g. the volume form on any generic holonomy space. I have never really understood what's particularly special about the forms that do come from spinors vs those that don't, but I guess that's another question.

Comment: @PaulReynolds the "converse" that you mention has actually been studied recently in arXiv:1911.08658, where the authors characterize which polyforms can be written as the square of a spinor. It turns out that a polyform is the square of a spinor if and only if it satisfies a natural system of algebraic equations in the Kähler-Atiyah bundle of the underlying manifold.